# Laravel login, and after?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to laravel and I succeed to make authentication of a user, now I want to customize the view and the accessible links depending on the type of user. 
how can this be done with laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create different views according to your user type (ie user, admin...):

```
views/userPosts.blade.php
views/adminPosts.blade.php
```

And access them this way:

```
return View::make(Auth::user()->type.'Posts');
```

Or you can pass data to your views:

```
return View::make('posts')->with('user', Auth::user());
```

And in your view:

```
User name: {{$user->name}}
User e-mail: {{$user->email}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do that by protecting your routes... like so...

```
 Route::get('nameofroute', array('as' => 'name.route', 'before' => 'auth',
 'uses' => 'NameOfController@functionName'));
```

Furthermore in the view you can use

```
@if (Auth::user())
<div>now you see this</div>
@else
<div>now you see something else</div>
@endif
```

Comment: Yeah i realized that too late, seems you guys really love down-voting :-)

Comment: me guys loves upvoting as well.. But just giving an incorrect answer is not a reason for me to upvote ;)

Comment: My answer is perfectly correct man, what are you talking about.